# SQL Combing Columns in Select statements with Multiple Columns in each

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have two queries that each return two columns. They are:

---

```
SELECT
  visit.doctor_id,
  COUNT(
    visit.doctor_id)
  FROM
    visit
  GROUP BY
    visit.doctor_id
```

The result is

```
    Doctor ID | Visit Count
    4           20
    5           30
```

AND

```
SELECT
  procedures.surgeon,
  COUNT(
    procedures.surgeon)
  FROM
    procedures
  GROUP BY
    procedures.surgeon
```

The Result is

```
    Surgeon ID | Visit Count
    3           8
    9           13
```

I am trying to combine them into one table with all 4 columns. I can expand this later to add more.

I tried UNION but that gave me only two columns, I tried FULL UNION, and I tried to use SELECT (SELECT....) AS 'name', (SELECT....) AS 'NAME' however that did not work because each select statement puts out two columns instead of one. I also could not figure out how to use the JOIN function for this solution.

The result I want is

```
    Doctor ID | Doctor Visit Count  | Surgeon ID  | Surgeon Operation Count
    4           20                    3              8
    5           30                    9              13
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: JOIN is definitely what you are looking for here, what did you try with respect to JOINs?

Comment: Use back to back two CTEs and insert the result into another new table

Comment: Is there a relation between these two tables?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Now, add sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what the results would look like.

Comment: Using JOIN gave me errors with multiple select statements. I'm not sure how to apply them in this case I tried to use them the same was as UNION which I don't think is correct. Normally I would use an ON statement after JOIN but with no fields in common I am not sure how to make JOIN work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Cartesian Product when you are combining two tables with no common fields.

```
SELECT
    *
    FROM 
    (SELECT
      visit.doctor_id,
      COUNT(visit.doctor_id) AS 'COUNT'
      FROM visit
      GROUP BY visit.doctor_id) AS A,
    (SELECT
      procedures.surgeon,
      COUNT(procedures.surgeon) AS 'COUNT'
      FROM procedures
      GROUP BY procedures.surgeon) AS B
```

Comment: I get errors under the second and third SELECT statements, as well as each GROUP BY. When trying to run I get the errors:     An expression was expected. (near "(" at position 30)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 30)
This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "SELECT" at position 31)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 141)
Unexpected token. (near "," at position 142)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 149)
This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "SELECT" at position 150)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 274)